# How retrieve REDIRECT URL of an external page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, payment-gateway, redirect

We have an interesting use case that hopefully someone can help us achieve.

From our site `www.a.com` we want to host `www.b.com` in an iframe.

The challenge - to get the URL for www.b.com we first need to navigate to `www.a.com/page`. This page then redirects to `www.b.com` and includes security tokens in the URL (hence why we can't just set the URL on the iframe directly).

Is it possible in JavaScript to programmatically get the redirect URL from a different page that redirects?

The domain `a.com` does not allow content in iframes.

Comment: you want a redirect in javascript? like window.location.href = 'https://www.your-url.com/' ?

Comment: Hi Roy thanks for your suggestion. We can't simply do that as we don't know the query parameters that www.a.com/page puts in the URL when it redirects to www.b.com?param1=foo

Comment: This is not a simple redirect - please read the detail of the use case presented.  Thanks.

Comment: This is no way suspicious. We are using a payment gateway and we simply want to avoid our customers seeing our domain change when they proceed to payment.

Comment: @Roy: No, this is not a generic redirect. This is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: That is a very bad idea. Seeing the payment gateway’s address in the URL bar allows me to verify that I am actually entering my data to the genuine site, and not some clone of the site set up for phishing purposes.

Comment: @CBroe - you do have a valid point.

Comment: Perhaps the real security concern is why the payment gateway doesn't restrict its content being displayed in an iframe

Comment: Also in terms of security concerns - I beleive you can't retrieve the contents of an iframe that contains content from a different domain. I don't see how we would Capture payment info?